# Mat-form-field not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, input, angular-material, angular-forms

*Hi,
I went thru similar questions here but did not found solution for me so I am triing to ask with my code.
I am triing to create dialog with input fields using angular material mat-form-field.
This is my app.module.ts*

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { ProjectsOverviewComponent } from './overviews/projects-overview/projects-overview.component';
import { TicketsOverviewComponent } from './overviews/tickets-overview/tickets-overview.component';
import { UsersOverviewComponent } from './overviews/users-overview/users-overview.component';
import { MainMenuComponent } from './main-menu/main-menu.component';
import { UserBaseInfoComponent } from './user-base-info/user-base-info.component';
import { TicketBaseInfoComponent } from './ticket-base-info/ticket-base-info.component';
import { ProjectBaseInfoComponent } from './project-base-info/project-base-info.component';
import { ProjectsTableComponent } from './tables/projects-table/projects-table.component';
import { UsersTableComponent } from './tables/users-table/users-table.component';
import { TicketsTableComponent } from './tables/tickets-table/tickets-table.component';
import { PermisionsTableComponent } from './tables/permisions-table/permisions-table.component';
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './change-password/change-password.component';
import { AttributesTableComponent } from './tables/attributes-table/attributes-table.component';
import { AttributeValuesTableComponent } from './tables/attribute-values-table/attribute-values-table.component';
import { AttachmentsTableComponent } from './tables/attachments-table/attachments-table.component';
import { CommentsTableComponent } from './tables/comments-table/comments-table.component';
import { HistoryTableComponent } from './tables/history-table/history-table.component';
import { WorkflowTableComponent } from './tables/workflow-table/workflow-table.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatSidenavModule} from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import {MatToolbarModule} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatListModule} from "@angular/material/list";
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatGridListModule} from "@angular/material/grid-list";
import {MatTableModule} from "@angular/material/table";
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from "@angular/common/http";
import {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatFormFieldModule, MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatTooltipModule} from "@angular/material/tooltip";
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {MatSelectModule} from "@angular/material/select";
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { KeycloakAngularModule,  KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        realm: 'pato',
        url: 'http://localhost:8180/auth',
        clientId: 'angular-springboot'
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required'
      }
    });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    ProjectsOverviewComponent,
    TicketsOverviewComponent,
    UsersOverviewComponent,
    MainMenuComponent,
    UserBaseInfoComponent,
    TicketBaseInfoComponent,
    ProjectBaseInfoComponent,
    ProjectsTableComponent,
    UsersTableComponent,
    TicketsTableComponent,
    PermisionsTableComponent,
    ChangePasswordComponent,
    AttributesTableComponent,
    AttributeValuesTableComponent,
    AttachmentsTableComponent,
    CommentsTableComponent,
    HistoryTableComponent,
    WorkflowTableComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatTableModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatCardModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot({
      resourceServer: {
          allowedUrls: ['http://localhost:8080/api'],
          sendAccessToken: true
        }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    },
    {provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {appearance: 'fill'}}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*This is my dialog component html*

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>dialog title</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    

  <mat-form-field >
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput >
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onCancelClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Save</button>
</div>
```

Here is ts to component

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { TicketPostDto } from 'src/dtos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  newTicket: TicketPostDto = new TicketPostDto;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public ticket: TicketPostDto) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

*And here is my package.json in case it would help*

```
{
  "name": "pato-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.1.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^13.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "flexsearch": "^0.7.21",
    "keycloak-angular": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.6.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  }
}
```

This is error that I am getting

```
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
create-ticket-dialog.component.ts(12, 34): Error occurs in the template of component CreateTicketDialogComponent.
```

Comment: Which module declares the `CreateTicketDialogComponent`? You should import `MatFormFieldModule` in that module too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add your `DialogComponent` in your declarations array in the app.module.ts after importing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the dialog from `*.component.ts` and in the dialog used some other modules you must add all modules for dialog to `*.module.ts` (module file for component where you call the dialog)